# OpenCV cvtColor modifies original image too

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, hsv

I have a function that takes an image, converts it to HSV, and sets V to 100. However, it appears to modify the original image too.

```cpp
Mat hsvfilter(const Mat& img) {
  Mat result;
  cvtColor(img, result, CV_BGR2HSV);
  for (int j = 0; j < img.rows; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < img.cols; i++)
      result.at<Vec3d>(i, j)[2] = 100;
  return result;
}
```

Here's how I call it:

```cpp
Mat original = imread( "pic.png" );
Mat converted = hsvfilter(original);

namedWindow( "original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "original", original );

namedWindow( "converted", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "converted", converted );

waitKey(0);
```

Both the original image and the converted images end up having strange black vertical bars. I believe my code has some issues with pointers or memory, but I can't quite figure out where. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: HERE'S THE FIXED CODE**

```cpp
Mat hsvfilter(const Mat& img) {
  Mat result;
  cvtColor(img, result, CV_BGR2HSV);
  for (int j = 0; j < result.rows; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.cols; i++) {
      result.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i)[2] = 100;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: For a sanity check, try checking if the problem persists if you do `Mat converted = hsvfilter(original.clone());`. By cloning, there is no way the function access the memory of `original`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your hsvFilter function should looks like this:

   ```
   Mat hsvfilter(const Mat& img) {
   Mat result;
   cvtColor(img, result, CV_BGR2HSV);
   for (int j = 0; j < result.rows; j++) //you are modyfying "result" object, not img
      for (int i = 0; i < result.cols; i++) //same as above
         result.at<Vec3d>(j, i)[2] = 100; //OpenCV uses (y,x) indexing
   return result;
   }
   ```

   In this situation ther is no difference in using `img.cols`, `img.rows` / `result.cols`, `result.rows`, because size of both arrays (images) is the same, but generally don't forget about it :) The second comment doesn't need any more explanation.
2. Generally you code looks fine, in my opinion it should work. Did you try testing it without calling `hsvFilter` function (just display the original image)?
3. If you want to keep created windows for some time, use this code instead of `waitKey(0);`:

   ```
   while(waitKey(100) != 'q')
   {
       //all imshow calls
   }
   ```

Now, when you want to exit, just press 'q' (you need to have one of your app  windows active).

Comment: The problem was that OpenCV uses (y,x) indexing. I was probably accessing the matrix out of bounds, and instead of C++ throwing an error, it simply modified memory of the original matrix.